# Why isn't kilogram written as square kilogram ($\mathrm{kg^2}$) but meter is?

Tags: units, notation, si-units

I was wondering why some notations can be written with square and some can't.

Comment: This question is unclear

Comment: There's no reason why some units couldn't contain  mass squared, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Kilogram isn't written as kg^2, because it's written as kg.  Meter is not written as m^2 because it's written as m.  Square kilograms are written kg^2 and square meters are written m^2.

Answer (score 10):

There is no reason why a quantity cannot be defined in units of kg-squared.

For  example, gravitational attraction depends on the product of 2 masses; this product could be given a name and quantified in units of $kg^2$. Likewise the magnetic force between two current-carrying wires depends on the product of the currents; this product would be measured in the unusual units of Amps-squared ($A^2$). This combination does in fact occur quite often within electo-magnetic units, but it has no special significance and no name.

The reason we don't do this already is that it is not useful, unlike $m^2$ for area and $m^3$ for volume, which are useful quantities.